# Confused about how my routes are interacting with each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Ok, I'm gonna try to get as specific as I can.  Here's my code:

**routes.rb**

```
root to: "users#index"
match "/users/:id/about", to: "users#about", as: :about
match "/users/:id/blog", to: "users#blog", as: :blog
match "users/:id/contact", to: "users#contact", as: :user_contact
match "/contact", to: "static_pages#contact", as: :static_contact

resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users do
  resources :portfolios do
    resources :pictures
  end
end
```

Here's my navigation bar with all the links on my main page:

```
 <nav>
    <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav">
      <li class="<%= "selected" if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "home", root_path %></li>
      <li class="<%= "selected" if current_page?(about_path) %>"><%= link_to "about me", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "my portfolio" %>
        <ul>
          <% @user.portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
            <li><%= link_to portfolio.name, user_portfolio_path(@user, portfolio) %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="<%= "selected" if current_page?(blog_path) %>"><%= link_to "blog", blog_path %></li>
      <li class="<%= "selected" if current_page?(user_contact_path) %>"><%= link_to "contact", user_contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

When I link from any link (home, about me, blog, contact) to any other link everything works fine.  For example when I'm on the about me page (/users/8/about) I can link to the contact page(users/8/contact).  The problem is when I land on the portfolio page (/users/8/portfolios/31) and try to link to the about me page, for example, the url becomes this: /users/31/about instead of back to /users/8/about.  User 31 doesn't exist but portfolio 31 exists.

Comment: <% @user.portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
<li><%= link_to portfolio.name, user_portfolio_path(@user, portfolio) %></li>
<% end %>

Comment: ... To the thing that's being linked to incorrectly.

Comment: I'm linking from url users/8/portfolios/31 to about_path which I defined above.  When I link from, for example, users/8/contact to about_path it correctly links to url users/8/about.

Comment: How and where, *precisely* (e.g., edit your question to include what you're actually doing), do you create the link to the `about` page which creates the error? We don't need a vague description of what you're doing--that won't allow us to help. We need specifics.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with not providing an id (e.g., a user) to the path. What happens if you pass in the user? It's probably taking the most-specific "thing"'s ID, in this case, the portfolio.

Comment: Well my about route looks like this: /users/:id/about, so the number in the middle gets param name :id.  But the show action for a portfolio looks like this: /users/:user_id/portfolios/:id so it's taking the portfolio :id and pluging it into as the user :id

Comment: Which is why I suggested providing an argument to `about_path`; are you saying it doesn't take one?

Comment: no it doesn't take one

Comment: I see. Then you probably should have handled this by creating [additional REST actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) so you could properly parameterize resource-specific routes.

Comment: ok, I'll try playing around with that.